# Type-safe way to store two types of object in a collection

Tags: c#, collections, types, heterogeneous

I've been implementing an enhanced Shunting-Yard algorithm for parsing an arithmetic expression. One aspect of the algorithm, is that it maintains a `Queue`, and a `Stack`.

In my implementation, the `Queue` contains `Expressions` and `Operators`.
The `Stack` contains `Operators` and `Parenthesis`.

`Expressions`, `Parenthesis`, and `Operators` have nothing in common that warrants any two of them having a shared interface.

**Approaches:**

- My current implementation consists of `Expression` and `Operator` implementing a `INotParanthesis`. `Operator` and `Paranthesis` implement a `INotExpression`. I then declare `Queue <INotParanthesis>`, and `Stack <INotExpression>`.

  I don't like this implementation - these interfaces seem very much a hack for the purpose of cleaner algorithm code. I also believe that interfaces should describe what an object is, as opposed to what it isn't.
- On the other hand, I also don't want to use collections of `<Object>`, as it can be difficult to be certain of the correctness of such code.
- The only one I've come up with, so far, is implementing my own `NonParanthesisQueue` and `NonExpressionStack` containers. This has the advantage of more consistent type checking on objects getting pulled out of those containers - and the disadvantage of a lot more code.

Are there any reasonable alternatives to my approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a sum type. Although C# does not have these built in, there's a trick from functional programming that you can use called Church encoding to achieve this. It's completely type safe with no casts involved, however it's a bit weird to use in C# mostly due to the limitations of the type inference.

The main trick is that instead of using properties and checks to retrieve one of the two alternatives, we have a higher order function `Map` that takes two functions as arguments and calls the appropriate one depending on which alternative was present. Here's how you would use it:

```
var stack = new Stack<IEither<Operator, Parenthesis>>();

stack.Push(new Left<Operator, Parenthesis>(new Operator()));
stack.Push(new Right<Operator, Parenthesis>(new Parenthesis()));

while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    stack.Pop().Map(op  => Console.WriteLine("Found an operator: " + op),
                    par => Console.WriteLine("Found a parenthesis: " + par));
}
```

Here's the implementation of `IEither`, `Left` and `Right`. They are fully generic and could be used anywhere you want a sum type.

```
public interface IEither<TLeft, TRight>
{
    TResult Map<TResult>(Func<TLeft, TResult> onLeft, Func<TRight, TResult> onRight);
    void Map(Action<TLeft> onLeft, Action<TRight> onRight);
}

public sealed class Left<TLeft, TRight> : IEither<TLeft, TRight>
{
    private readonly TLeft value;

    public Left(TLeft value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TResult Map<TResult>(Func<TLeft, TResult> onLeft, Func<TRight, TResult> onRight)
    {
        return onLeft(value);
    }

    public void Map(Action<TLeft> onLeft, Action<TRight> onRight)
    {
        onLeft(value);
    }
}

public sealed class Right<TLeft, TRight> : IEither<TLeft, TRight>
{
    private readonly TRight value;

    public Right(TRight value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TResult Map<TResult>(Func<TLeft, TResult> onLeft, Func<TRight, TResult> onRight)
    {
        return onRight(value);
    }

    public void Map(Action<TLeft> onLeft, Action<TRight> onRight)
    {
        onRight(value);
    }
}
```

---

References:

- [Tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)
- [Algebraic data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type)
- [Church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)

Comment: @Vladislav this is similar to rationull's answer (basically the idea is to use a tuple type to hold heterogeneous data) but I guess you could combine the ideas of both to make it even shorter (I say this 'cos you like it to be less verbose).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could define a small holder type for each, one with an Expression property and an Operator property and the other with an Operator property and a Parenthesis property. Accessors and constructors could assert or otherwise ensure that only one is populated. The queue and the stack would each contain the appropriate holder type.

A little awkward but typesafe and workable.

Hopefully someone will have a more clever idea.

Comment: Thanks - that is not something I've considered - and definitely makes sense, albeit a little verbose.